# Java - get information into library project from project which includes this library

Tags: java, android, static, parent-child, abstract-class

I am developing a library which needs some configuration information from project which would include this library. What I was thinking is to having some abstract methods in my library and force application to implement these methods.
What I am looking for is:

1. Class A in library having some **static abstract methods**, say
   having a method named getURL();
2. A class B implements these static
   methods in actual application and implement method getURL() from
   class A.
3. In my library, I called A.getURL(), it should call method
       implementation from class B which extends class A and should return me the url.

But an abstract method can't be static in Java. Is there some workaround to achieve same like functionality.

Comment: Why does it need to be static?  If you had a non-static class in your library you could pass your 'configuration' as parameters to the constructor/factory methods.

Comment: Actually, application does not create any object of any class of library. Library have Main class with it and it needs some information from application to start its actual work.

Comment: When an Application starts it will only run 1 main method.  This method should be considered as just the "Entry point" to the program and shouldn't do much functional stuff itself.  If you have two applications running then it isn't really a library any more.  I recommend you change your library implementation to use an object.  Perhaps you could provide some more information to help us improve these answers.

Comment: Right, let me explain. For simplicity I was using main class. Actually this is an android project. Library have a specific menu and web service component. All work done by lib is dynamic. Lib needs menu names and corresponding classes names from a project which includes it. But for security it would not disclose the control flows or any of its class snippet to Application which using it. I want to add some sort of interface between both applications to share configuration etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public abstract class A {

    protected static A INSTANCE;

    public static String getURL() {
        return INSTANCE.getURL();
    }

    protected abstract String getURL0();
}
```

---

```
class B extends A {

    static {
        INSTANCE = new B();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getURL0() {
        return "application-specific url";
    }
}
```

Comment: Also B class initialization is required before of A.getURL() usage

Comment: How do I initialize B as my lib don't know which class have extended class A in application.

Comment: Ok, library know only about class A.

But application know about class B. Therefore you should to ensure the initialization of B class in the application before of usage static getURL() method.

Answer (score 1):

A static abstract method makes no sense, since the notion that an abstract method should be implemented by an extending class (which is part of OO), and static denotes a non instance method (not OO).

But I had a similar problem in a J2EE project recently, in which the library needed some specific configuration depending on the project that used it.

What we decided to do is to have a configuration file with a specific name in the project, that the library should read as soon as loaded. If the file and/or the required configurations were not found, an exception is thrown (you can create your own).

I think this way you can decouple implementation of the library from the projects using it.

Comment: Thanks Thiago Veronese, same situation I am facing. Configuration file is not suitable for the situation I am facing. Application may need to provide dynamic information in some situations.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your answers to questions I would recommend the following:

Define an interface for a class that retrieves the properties like so:

```
interface LibaryDetails {

    URL getURL();

    String getName();
}
```

Then create a Factory method of some kind which causes your Library to run and do it's thing.  Refactor your code out of the main so it can be accessed from here.  Have this method take the interface as a parameter:

```
public class LibraryFactory{
    public static void startLibrary(LibaryDetails details){
        URL url = details.getURL();
        String name = details.getName();
        // start Library things
    }
}
```

Now your Library only needs to expose the interface and the static Factory.  Your Applications just needs to pass it's implementation of the LibraryDetails interface to the factory method and your library can access the information.